# Initiate POST Request, Perform Action, Then Complete Post request - how?

Tags: php, javascript

When a user clicks a submit button I want the form to be submitted. However, just before this happens, I want a window to pop open and for them to fill in some data. Once they do this and they close that child window, I want the POST request to be made.

Is this **possible**, if so **how**? I just need help after the window closes, how can I make that POST request continue?

Thanks all

Comment: Do you want the data from the child window to be submitted with the original post?

Comment: No, the child window will not submit anything. Just some extra info: the child window will actually fire off a function of the parent window to tell it "everything is ok" and the form can be submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just add a

```
onunload=parent.form.submit()?
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onunload.asp

Comment: I just found out about that beautiful function. Thank you for your reply. [SOLVED]

Comment: But then the form is always submitted, even if the user doesn't fill it out, just by trying to leave the page.

Comment: not if you hook the onload handler before when you call window.close();

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.. (note the code is simplified and you can probably structure it better)

This is in your main document with the form:

```
var childFilled = false;
myForm.onsubmit = function() {
    if(!childFilled) {
        window.open(...);
        return false;
    }
};

function submitFormFromChild() { 
    childFilled = true;
    myForm.submit();
}
```

And in the window's code you have something like this:

```
window.onunload = parent.submitFormFromChild;
```

Untested, unproven, but the general concept is something like this =)

Answer (score 0):

To be clear: you meant to ask (and asked in the question) how to intercept form-submission in the browser.

The title of your post implies that you are asking how to perform an asynchronous HTTP POST operation, do something else, and subsequently wait for that HTTP POST operation to complete. That whole process is not necessarily related to user interaction and is not necessarily related to HTML form submission, and it is not the same thing at all as what you meant to ask (and asked in the question).